# Передача экземпляра PDO в родитель модели MVC

Tags: pdo, php, mvc

Как это можно сделать без костылей и бубнов?

Желательно такого вида:

```
try { 
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
} catch (PDOException $e) { 
    die('PDO->ERROR::'.$e->getMessage());
}
```

---

Решил попробовать Singleton :

```
class DB extends PDO {
    private $db;
    public static $Instance = NULL;
    public static function Instance() {
        if (self::$Instance == NULL) {
              self::$Instance = new self();
            }
            return self::$Instance;
    }
    public function __construct() {
        $this->db =  new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    }
    public function prepare($sql, $values) {
        $sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute($values);
    }
}
```

Но опять же ошибки ...

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in.

Как их избежать не делая обертку?

Comment: Синглетон вполне подойдёт.

>>> Но опять же ошибки Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in. 

Полностью текст сообщения покажи и текст около той строки, на которую указывает ошибка.

Comment: у синглетона метод `__construct` является protected, чтобы "снаружи" не делали `$db = new DB;`

Comment: public function prepare($sql, $values) {
        $sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute($values);
        return $sth; // вот это забыл сделать
    }

Comment: Синглетон используется так:

    function doSomeStreetMagic() {
        $db = DB::Instance();
        $sth = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM user');
        while($row = $sth->fetch()) {
            // look strange at the camera
        }
    }

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev благодарю, уже догадался, перечитав мануалы несколько раз.

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev, protected на конструкторе вызывает ошибку Fatal error: Access level to DB::__construct() must be public (as in class PDO) in D:\OpenServer\domains\one.ru\engine\DB.php on line 20

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на реализацию [компонент и модулей в фреймворке Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CComponent)

Например

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM user');
```

на самом деле читает конфиг для компоненты `db`, и берёт оттуда имя класса. Затем инстанциирует экземпляр класса с параметрами, заданными в конфиге же и сохраняет инстанс в реестре компонент под кодом `db`. При последующем запросе Yii::app()->dbинстанс с кодом `db` берётся из реестра. В общем - основная идея - нужен глобальный **реестр сущностей** с удобным публичным доступом и тогда экземпляр PDO не надо будет передавать в родитель, он сам его найдёт по одному общесистемному имени `db`.

Comment: мне кажется это огромным и сложным

Comment: Да ну вас, прямо скажу. Огромное. А вы конечно придумаете компактного мастадонта, ручного можно сказать.
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/base/CComponent.php если убрать комменты, то будет от силы 200 строк. Но коменты то надо прочитать - на то они и коменты.


Я ещё раз повторяю: нужен глобальный __реестр сущностей__ с удобным публичным доступом и тогда экземпляр PDO не надо будет передавать в родитель, он сам его найдёт по одному общесистемному имени db.

Comment: Ну я конечно вру. На самом деле конечно сложно. Просто я уже привык и сложность не замечаю. Там вся магия в магическом методе __get()

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev я же говорю это сложно, долго и громоздка.

Comment: Реестр - это полумеры. Если уж делать, то полноценный DI, для простой реализации там тоже не так уж много строк потребуется.

Answer (score 0):

если я вас правильно понял, то как-то так

```
class Foo
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $pdo = new PDO();
        parent::__construct($pdo);
    }
}
```

Comment: вот смотрите у меня есть

model_me extends model {
function me() {
тут я выполняю свои действия с бд (и у меня возникают проблемы с тем что к примеру $db->prepare() вызывает ошибку Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in)
}
}

и я не знаю что мне делать

Comment: очень сильно не хочется делать обертки.

Comment: @Eugene Smiths может надо $this->db использовать ?

Comment: @eicto оно и так используется.

Comment: Не понимаю, что ты имеешь в виду под "очень сильно не хочется делать обертки."

Comment: Интересно, наступит ли когда-нибудь тот день, когда пользователи пыхапешечки перестанут создавать в каждом объекте свое собственное соединение с БД с чарсетом и запросами.